# Browserify Shim Buffer core module

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm trying to browserify my library where there are `Buffer` core module being use in different places.

I want to shim this core `Buffer` with another library that we are using.

I have tried to look into https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim where I can specify my module that I want to shim but it doesn't seem to work.

I've created file called `shim.js`

```
var Buffer = require('myModule').Buffer;

module.exports = {
  Buffer: { exports: Buffer }
};
```

in `Package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "MD5": "^1.2.1",
    "browser-request": "^0.3.1",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.6.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "browserify-shim": "./shims.js"
}
```

And in `Gruntfile.js` (I'm using `grunt-browserify`)

```
browserify: {
    src: "./index.js",
    options: {
      transform: ['browserify-shim'],
      browserifyOptions: {
        builtins: false
      },
      bundleOptions: {
        standalone: "mylibrary"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Right now when I grunt build the file I'm still seeing this being require in:

```
[function(_dereq_,module,exports){
(function (Buffer){
```

And in my browser is complaining about

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "buffer" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```